# How to find nearby objects using Easting and Northing range

Tags: c#, coordinates

I have a bunch of objects which have associated Eastings and Northings in format OSGB36

for example:

```
265397  869562
547297  179002
```

If I have a starting Easting and Northing, and wanted to find related objects within X km is it possible to compute a Start/End Northing and Start/End Easting range that I can search for programatically?

I am using C#.

I.e. searching for objects using pseudo-code :

```
Easting >= 265390 && Easting <= 265400 &&
Northing >= 869560 && Northing <= 869564
```

would this find nearby objects? What resolution do these coordinates operate to?
I can operate in miles or km, just need to know the scale - if such a thing is possible.

Sorry this is new to me.

Comment: Further to Polygeo's comment, could you also say what coordinate reference system those eastings and northings are in? If UTM, which UTM zone?

Comment: Sorry for lack of detail - edited post as requested.

Comment: See http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/os/data_information/os_data_issues/ng_converter.htm for help on precision of OSGB map refs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [National Grid Reference Converter](http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/os/data_information/os_data_issues/ng_converter.htm) for help on the precision of OSGB map references.

If you just use a search range to create a box surrounding your query point, as indicated by

```
(east_QP - range)  <= east  <= (east_QP + range)
(north_QP - range) <= north <= (north_QP + range)
```

a variation on your pseudo code, it is fast but biased.

If you "create a circle" around your query point

```
hypot ((east_QP - east), (north_QP - north)) <= range
```

where `hypot()` computes distance, it is a tiny bit slower but less biased as it cuts out the box corners.